# HttpURLConnection not working over 3g only wifi

Tags: java, android, base64, httpurlconnection, 3g

I have created a app that  reads a json file across the internet.
My app seems to work fine over wifi but when i use 3g  it does not work for me on the orange network. I have a friend who tried it on a different network over 3g and it did work. I can browse the internet on 3g so i know i have a connection

I have added some debug code and found that its a `IOException` file not found if that helps, but why can it find it on wifi?

My code is as follows:

```
        String addr = "http://policeapi2.rkh.co.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=" + strLat + "&lng=" + strLng;
        URL url = new URL(addr);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        String data = "user:password";
        String encoding = Base64.encodeToString(data.getBytes("US-ASCII"), Base64.DEFAULT);

        conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);

        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.connect();

        InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
```

Comment: First of all, Have you tried using `HttpGet`?

You can workaround it. By determining on which connection is currently running, is it either Wifi or 3g. if it is wifi run this code and if it is 3g running `HttpGet` (supposing it will work)

Comment: What's the actual exception?  Is it a timeout?  WIFI is faster than 3G so if the server is lollygagging on getting the response out it could be just that small different in latency between them that causes one to work and the other to fail.  But, we won't know without the exception.

Comment: @chubbard he mentioned the exception. I'm not sure either. Maybe the cause of the exception is something else. He needs to put the logcat.

Comment: Yea, but I don't know if that even goes with this code as we don't have the stacktrace.  If we had the actual text we could see if this code is associated with that exception or not.  If that exception is really even involved or just another issue.

Comment: I can guess if it is matter of timeout then `HttpURLConnection` object remains null thus `NPE` is thrown...or some timeout exception. :P :D

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I solved removing the User-Agent in the connection as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12664098/616583