# Android URLConnection does only work in wifi, not with 3g

Tags: android, 3g, urlconnection, wifi

I have written an app which uses an URLConnection to get a .html file. 
Everything works fine over wifi. But over 3g the file is not returned correctly. 
When i try to access the website via the browser it works fine. 
Anyone has a suggestion?

Update: 
Here is my code:

```
URL downloadUrl;
URLConnection downloadConnection;
InputStream inputStream;
byte[] inputBytes;
String[] output;
private void downloadSource(String pUrl)
{

    try
    {
        downloadUrl = new URL(pUrl);

        downloadConnection = downloadUrl.openConnection();
        downloadConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        downloadConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);


        inputStream = downloadConnection.getInputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        inputBytes = new byte[10000];
        int i;
        int i1 = 0;
        while ((i = inputStream.read(inputBytes)) > 0)
        {
            result.write(inputBytes, 0, i);
            result.flush();
            i1 += i;
        }
        result.flush();
        result.close();
        output = result.toString().split("\n"); 

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: could you please provide the code? Also attach the log-file if possible.

Comment: I added it to the question. The log-file does not contain anything for this.

Comment: can you ping the URL while on 3G network?

Comment: Yes i can ping it without any problem.

Comment: I just noticed that some part of the document is downloaded, but it doesn't contain any newline characters. So everything is written into output[0]. But it does only write about 4000 chars to it.

Comment: very interesting. so the difference between Wlan and 3G is only the line breaks? Are there "\r" in the returned file?

Comment: No there are even no "\r" in it. It seems like the lines are just seperated by spaces.

Comment: insane. i have no reasonable idea for this, but maybe it works with a different user-agent?

Comment: I will try that. thanks. But i just noticed that when i am trying it with another url and splitting the result at "\r" i get some lines of a script at output[1] to output[7] and the last index contains the footer of the page. Maybe the ByteArrayOutputStream can't handle more then 4000 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a little bit late for answer but I had the same problem, with Wifi the html downloaded had different spaces than the one downloaded with 3G.

I solved it deleting the User-Agent in the connection:

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();  
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","");
```

I hope it helps someone!